# VB.NET "Value cannot be Null Parameter Name: Source" when using a Boolean value of False

Tags: vb.net

I am beginning in coding, using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2019. I'm having a curious problem that I don't understand.
My program is simple and intended, currently, to run through a very large .txt file (nearly 3 million lines), find a certain string value (the values are delimited by "," - it's comma separated value) and let me know if the string value has been found, and if it has, the line number. If not, I just want a label I placed to display "File not found". The program works, I do get either the "File found on (line number)" if I type a corresponding value or "File not found", but AFTER the program has finished, and worked, I get an argument null exception saying "Value cannot be Null, Parameter Name: Source". I'm not sure what it is objecting to. Possibly it is because I created a Boolean value "False" for if the string value is not found, but I've searched all over the Microsoft documentation and can't find anything that suggests that is not allowed.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim File_name As String
    File_name = "C:\New Folder\Programming\Residual Stressn.txt"

    Dim entr As String
    entr = TextBox1.Text

    Dim Txter As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(File_name)

    Txter.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    Txter.SetDelimiters(",")


    While Not Txter.EndOfData
        Txter.ReadFields()
        If Txter.ReadFields.Contains(entr) = True Then Label1.Text = "File Found on line " & Txter.LineNumber
        If Txter.ReadFields.Contains(entr) = False Then Label2.Text = "File Not found"
    End While

    MsgBox("Enter next command")

End Sub
```

As I said, the program runs, both labels work. It just kicks up bobsy-die after it has finished.
The parameter, if it is referring to "entr", is not empty. I always put a string value in the text box during run time. And it didn't get cranky with me until I added label2 and the "false" value. But surely if I am allowed to enter a Boolean value, which I can with readfields.contains, then I should be able to put "false"? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Surround the code with `try...catch` block to get more details on the exception. You may also find a sample code here as well - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-comma-delimited-text-files

Comment: Your `While` loop never ends after finding something - it will continue even after finding something and continuously update Label1 or Label2 until the file has ended.

Answer (score 2):

This is very bad:

```vb
While Not Txter.EndOfData
    Txter.ReadFields()
    If Txter.ReadFields.Contains(entr) = True Then Label1.Text = "File Found on line " & Txter.LineNumber
    If Txter.ReadFields.Contains(entr) = False Then Label2.Text = "File Not found"
End While
```

You are reading three lines on every iteration and you will often get an incorrect result.

Every time you call `ReadFields` you are reading a line of the file. You have three calls to `ReadFields` in that loop so you will read three lines of the file on every iteration. The first line reads a line of the file and just throws it away. The second line reads another line of the file and does something only if it contains the specified text. The third line reads yet another line of the file and does something only if the line doesn't contain the specified text. That is working only by accident and will not work in every case. That code should look like this:

```vb
Dim lineNumber As Integer? = Nothing

While Not Txter.EndOfData
    If Txter.ReadFields.Contains(entr) Then
        lineNumber = Txter.LineNumber
        Exit While
    End If
End While

If lineNumber.HasValue Then
    Label1.Text = "File Found on line " & lineNumber
Else
    Label2.Text = "File Not found"
End If
```

Only one line of the file is read at a time and examined. If that line contains the specified text then the search ends. If the search gets to the end of the file without finding the specified text, only then is it reported that it was not found. I've maintained the fact that you are using two different `Labels` and bad casing of your text.

Just to illustrate how bad that existing code is, imagine that you have a file like this:

```
X
Y
Z
X
Y
Z
```

and the value you were looking for was "Z". On the first iteration of the loop, your code would first read "X" and throw it away, then read "Y" and `Contains` would return `False` so it would not record the value as found, then read "Z" and `Contains` would return `True` so the value would not be recorded as not found either. The same thing would happen on the second iteration. In two iterations of the loop you would read six lines of the file and, despite the value being present on two of those lines, you would not record the value as either found or not found. Like I said, when that code worked, it was simply by luck.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error with (integer).HasValue. It would appear that is not a recognised command. Possibly because I am using a different version of Visual Studio to you? Anyway, thanks for the feedback, most helpful.

Comment: Integer has no 'HasValue'. Integer? = Nullable integer has this property. Check the '?' at the end on the type

Comment: @Mimsy32, as suggest, `lineNumber` is not type `Integer`. It is type `Nullable(Of Integer)`, which is abbreviated to `Integer?`. Nullable value types were introduced in .NET 2.0 with VB 2005 and that shorthand was introduced in VB 2008 I believe, or maybe VB 2010. You are using the very same version of VS as I am.

Comment: OK, what I did instead was make the code:  (integer)=>0. That worked well.

Comment: @Mimsy32, that will certainly work but it's not as correct. Using magic numbers like that should be avoided if possible. It wasn't possible in VB originally, before nullable value types, which is why you'll find -1 used in that sort of situation quite a bit. If you are going to use an `Integer` then I suggest that you use -1 as well but it would be better if you used an `Integer?`, which is why I did.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your loop as follows:

```
Dim Found As String = Nothing
While Not Txter.EndOfData AndAlso Found Is Nothing
    Found = Txter.ReadFields()
    If Found.Contains(entr) Then Label1.Text = "File Found on line " & Txter.LineNumber Else Found = Nothing
End While
If Found Is Nothing Then Label2.Text = "File Not found"
```

This will stop searching once it finds something.

Comment: That code doesn't look right to me. Should the second condition in your loop criteria be negated?

Comment: I don't think so. The loop should continue as long as `Found` is Nothing.

Comment: Yes, but the result of `ReadFields` is assigned to `Found` on the first iteration and that won't be `Nothing` so the loop will exit before the second iteration. Are you familiar with the `TextFieldParser` class and it's `ReadFields` method? Perhaps not. It is going to return a `String` array containing the field values from a line of text in a CSV file. That won't be `Nothing` as long as there is data to read.

Answer (score 0):

I personally never used (or even heard about) the TextFieldParser class. Some googling showed up some performance issues. However, I would go with String-/StreamReader (or here with the System.IO.File.ReadAllLines...).
In general, in your program you enter the filename in a TextBox and look up, if the filename exist or not, meaning, every time you parse the whole file again and again? Wouldn't be a considerable approach to read the file into a List and doing the lookup on the list?

I assume you use WinForms as GUI, so you could place a private variable in the Form.vb

```
Dim contents as List(Of String)
Dim File_name = "C:\New Folder\Programming\Residual Stressn.txt" 'Since this seems to be static, you can declare it on class level
```

Read the File on first click

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

  If contents Is Nothing Then
    contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (File_Name).ToList() ' Add: Imports System.Linq
  End If

  Dim entr = TextBox1.Text 'TextBox.Text is always string, don't need to declare the type

  'Since you only care about the Filename contained in the line, and don't need the structured field contents
  Dim index = contents.FindIndex(0, contents.Count -1, Function (str as String) str.Contains(entr))
  If  index <> -1 Then
    Label1.Text = "File Found on line " & index
  Else
    Label2.Text = "File Not found"
  End If
End Sub
```

Haven't used VB for a while so I hope it compiles, but the idea should be clear

Comment: There are some issues with your proposed solution. The code in the question is only matching full field values where you are match partial values or even combined values. If a line was "ABC,123,XYZ" and the value of interest was "2" then your code would record a match whereas the original code would not. This is a CSV file and the matching is being done on field values but you haven't allowed that.

Comment: Also, one advantage of the `TextFieldParser` is that it is specifically designed to read delimited files, so it can handle quoted text that may or may not contain field delimiters and/or record delimiters. It may not be an issue in this case but a proper CSV file could have a field wrapped in quotes and containing a line break. Your code would treat that as two separate records. If you were to split a line on the commas then you'd have to allow for a field that could be wrapped in quotes and contained a comma. This may be why the `TextFieldParser` can be slower but it does things right.

Comment: you're  right about your comment, depending of the csv (no info provided) structure and the loookup style it could fit (even on extending with an Split, or introducing a type for the line data, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your original code reads three lines on each cycle of the loop

I'm presuming that you want the search to stop as soon as you've found the first occurrence of the search string, so it could look like this..

Its similar to other answers and this is my take on it. It looks pretty clean, but constructive criticism is always appreciated

```
    Dim stringFound As Boolean = False
    While Not Txter.EndOfData And Not stringFound
        Dim fields As String() = Txter.ReadFields()
        If fields.Contains(entr) = True Then
            Label1.Text = "File Found on line " & Txter.LineNumber
            stringFound = True
        End If
    End While
    If Not stringFound Then Label2.Text = "File Not found"
```